# NullPointerException with Dagger 2 injection

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I'm using dagger 2.0.2 and I'm having a NullPointerException here `storage.getUserId()` only 10% of the users get it.

The app will launch and sometime will crash, you restart it, and everyting is fine.

I tried the Snapshot version because I found this https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/214

But I'm still having the issue, but now only about 2%, which is still not normal.

LaunchActivity

```
public class LaunchActivity extends CustomActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String userId = storage.getUserId(); //crash here storage is null
    }
}
```

CustomActivity

```
public abstract class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    protected Storage storage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Injector.INSTANCE.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

AppContextComponent

```
public interface AppContextComponent {
    CustomApplication application();
    Storage provideStorage();
}
```

AppContextModule

```
@Module
public class AppContextModule {
    private final CustomApplication application;

    public AppContextModule(CustomApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    public CustomApplication application() {
        return this.application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Storage provideStorage() {
        return new Storage();
    }
}
```

ApplicationComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={AppContextModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(CustomActivity activity);
    void injectApp(CustomApplication application);
}
```

Injector class

```
public enum Injector {
    INSTANCE;

    private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    private Injector(){
    }

    public void initializeApplicationComponent(CustomApplication customApplication) {
        ApplicationComponent applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .appContextModule(new AppContextModule(customApplication))
                .build();
        this.applicationComponent = applicationComponent;

    }

    public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
        return applicationComponent;
    }
}
```

Comment: *It looks fine.* You should try addind log output and debugging it. Also, issue 214 should not apply to you, since you don't seem to inject in your subclass.

Comment: Your `ApplicationComponent` should extend `AppContextComponent` to have the provision methods.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce all the tutorial and doc i've doesn't do that.

Comment: Well, you **are** using a single `@Singleton` scoped component, so you won't end up with problems due to not having the provision methods in your `ApplicationComponent` but if that ever happens; that is why.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but how can this be intermittent, if I really did forget something, it would crash for all users, not just a subset

Comment: I just got an idea, can you show your Application class?